# Robot Framework Regular Expression with Dot All

Tags: python, robotframework

I am not able to figure out how to do re.DOTALL equivalent in robot framework
Why the below regex is not matching?

```
'(?s).*Total Test Cases executed.*' does not match '
Sleep for 10 sec

 Total Test Cases executed :  1
 Total Test Cases Passed   :  1
 Total Test Cases Failed   :  0
 Total Test Cases Aborted  :  0'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax looks ok, and it works for me:

```
${test}=   Catenate    SEPARATOR=\n
...     Sleep for 10 sec

...     Total Test Cases executed: 1
...     Total Test Cases Passed:1
...     Total Test Cases Failed: 0
...     Total Test Cases Aborted: 0

Should Match Regexp     ${test}     (?s).*Total Test Cases executed.*
${matches}=     Get Regexp Matches   ${test}     (?s).*Total Test Cases executed.*
```

Both `Should Match Regexp` and `Get Regexp Matches` successfully find the line.

Looking at your error though, please check how you are calling the keywords - the first argument should be the string, and the 2nd the pattern.
*(when the regexp doesn't match anything, the output is `'string'  does not match 'pattern'`, it looks reversed in your error)*

Comment: Thanks!. It was so silly of me to not figure that out by myself.